# Python: getting max of a of a {(tuple): value } dictionary per fieldname in tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max, tuples

another list-dictionary question.

I have a dict as follows with unit names and testnames in a list:

```
dictA = {('unit1', 'test1'): 10,  ('unit2', 'test1'): 78,  ('unit2', 'test2'): 2, ('unit1', 'test2'): 45}

units = ['unit1', 'unit2'] 
testnames = ['test1','test2']
```

How do we find the max of the values for each test in testnames:

I tried as follows:

```
def max(dict, testnames_array):
    maxdict = {}
    maxlist = []
    temp = []
    for testname in testnames_array:
        for (xunit, xtestname), value in dict.items():
            if xtestname == testname:
                if not isinstance(value, str):
                    temp.append(value)
            temp = filter(None, temp)
            stats = corestats.Stats(temp) 
            k = stats.max() #finds the max of a list using another module
            maxdict[testname] = k
    maxlist.append(maxdict)
    maxlist.insert(0,{'Type':'MAX'})
    return maxlist
```

Problem now is that im getting output:

```
[{'Type':'MAX'}, {'test1': xx}, {'test2':xx}]
```

where xx is all returned as a same values!!

where is my fault?
any simpler methods?
please advice. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> dictA = {('unit1', 'test1'): 10,  ('unit2', 'test1'): 78,  ('unit2', 'test2'): 2, ('unit1', 'test2'): 45}
>>> maxDict={}
>>> for (unitName,testName),grade in dictA.items():
    maxDict[testName]=max(maxDict.get(testName,0),grade)


>>> maxDict
{'test1': 78, 'test2': 45}
```

I guess this should solve it.

Comment: +1 Similar as my answer, but you got there first. (deleting mine)

Comment: @Shawn: Just saw your answer and I thought I double posted :)

Comment: +1 for `for (unitName,testName),grade` - I did not know that was possible!

Comment: may i know what happens here: `maxDict.get(testName,0),grade` ?

Comment: @siva: `maxDict.get(testName,0)` means return the value for the testName in the maxDict dictionary. If the key does not exist, return 0. `max(maxDict.get(testName,0),grade)` compares the old grade to the new grade and returns the largest one. Hence, we compare each tests highest value to the new iterated value; if the new value is higher, it becomes the highest value.

Comment: @siva: This runs in linear time. It will possibly extend to tens of thousands without a problem. The best way to make sure is to test it.

Comment: @funktku: yeap, thanks. i have tested it but it seems, not returning the max value for hundreds of data points. still debugging. will update soon. cheers..

Comment: @funktku: i think my dict is contructed wrongfully. :( will ask a follow up question.

Comment: @funktku: it works. great! my dictionary was contructed wrongfuly.

Answer (score 0):

```
dictA = {('unit1', 'test1'): 10,  ('unit2', 'test1'): 78,  ('unit2', 'test2'): 2, ('unit1', 'test2'): 45}

def maxIndex(d, field=0):
    best = {}
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        index = k[field]
        try:
            old_v = best[index]
            best[index] = max(v, old_v)
        except KeyError:
            best[index] = v
    return best

maxIndex(dictA, 0)  # -> {'unit1': 45, 'unit2': 78}
maxIndex(dictA, 1)  # -> {'test1': 78, 'test2': 45}
```